# Excel: Counting the number of occurrences of similar rows of values in column, not pivot table, format

Tags: excel, csv

I know that you can use COUNTIF to count the number of occurrences of entries within a column of data, but how would you count the number of occurrences of matching values across a row? For example, if you have two columns of data:

```
5    6
5    6
5    5
2    5
3    6
2    5
5    6
```

How can you get this, with the third column being the number of occurrences of the pair:

```
5    6    3
5    5    1
2    5    2
3    6    1
```

Pivot tables give this information, but not in this format, which is useful for creating csv or tsv files of this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use COUNTIFS():

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,F1,B:B,G1)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: @interwebjill Refresh the screen, I forgot to calculate the sheet before copying and pasting the screen shot.  My calculation are set to manual.

Comment: Is there a way to get the search values in the F and G columns to be automatically generated from the existing data or do I have to manually enter every possible pair?

Comment: You can copy and paste the values then use Remove Duplicates.

Comment: Aha! Thank you! This is great for generating data for 2D heatmaps.